# c++ const for pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, const-correctness

a pointer to a constant int. I may change the pointer, but I may not change the value:

```
const int* a;
```

a constant pointer to an int. I may not change the pointer, but I may change the variable's value:

```
int* const a;
```

now, how do things look like if I'm dealing with a pointer to a pointer?

```
int** a;
```

how do I:

a) declare a const pointer to a non-const pointer to a non-const int

b) declare a non-const pointer to a const pointer to a non-const int

c) declare a non-const pointer to a non-const poiinter to a const int
?

Comment: I suggest typedefs.  Lots of typedefs.  Lots of typedefs that build on one another.  Enough typedefs that you hate life to such a degree that you avoid such foolishness in the future.  Yes, the distinction could be important.  No, I have never seen production code where it mattered.

Comment: To be fair:  "I have never NOTICED code where it mattered", in my 20+ year career as a programmer, most of which has been spent in C++.

Comment: this is more for my understanding of const-correctness than in order to write production code. I did stumble over it when I tried to replace a statically allocated `static const char* foo[1000]` with a dynamically allocated `static char** foo` and the compiler didn't allow me to assign string literals to the elements of foo

Comment: The `const` keyword binds to the thing to its immediate left.  (Unless `const` appears very first, in which case it binds to the thing to its immediate right.)

Comment: It’s worth noting that const-correctness isn’t a purely academic question if you write for embedded systems. In embedded applications, the `const` keyword signals an intention that the item should be stored in the device’s Program ROM rather than copied from that ROM to program RAM on startup. Most embedded systems have more ROM than RAM, so this is an important distinction when you’re close to the system’s memory limits.

Answer (score 3):

> a) declare a `const` pointer to a non-`const` pointer to a non-`const` `int`

```
int ** const a = nullptr;
```

Note that, since the pointer above is `const`-qualified it has to be initialized at the declaration. Otherwise, it won't compile.

> b) declare a non-`const` pointer to a `const` pointer to a non-`const` `int`

```
int * const *b;
```

> c) declare a non-`const` pointer to a non-`const` pointer to a `const` `int`

```
const int **c;
```

---

The pattern is, for a `const` pointer:

```
T * const ptr; // const pointer to T
```

and for a non-`const` pointer:

```
T * ptr; // non-const pointer to T
```

Then, select the proper pattern above for the outtermost pointer and replace `T` accordingly for the innermost pointer (i.e., the deepest one buried in the type):

- Non-`const` pointer to a non-`const` `int`: `T = int *`.
- `const` pointer to a non-`const` `int`: `T = int * const`.
- Non-`const` pointer to a `const` `int`: `T = const int *`.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about where the`const` is placed relative to the `*`: if `const` is on the left then what's pointed to is `const`, if `const` is on the right of `*` then what's pointing is `const`.